# asp.net looping through javascript files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to loop through my javascript files. In the global.asax file on application start, I have this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //bugs this line
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\Scripts");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in info.GetFiles("*.js"))
    {
        sb.Append(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(item.FullName));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

However, it's not working, it says it can't find files.
How do I programmatically get to a directory and its files?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is almost certainly not correct.

Use

```
string mappedPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Scripts");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(mappedPath);
```